# List is printing empty

Tags: java, list, wiktionary

I have a List in Java whose isEmpty() method returns false for some entries. Also when i check size for those entries it is One but when i print the List it is empty [].Is it because of whitespaces that List size is coming out to be One My Code is like this

```
    String str= "Meeting is scheduled";
      String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
      for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
    // Retrieve all IWiktionaryEntries for the words in a String "str".
        List<IWiktionaryEntry> entries = wkt.getEntriesForWord(strArray[i].trim());
        if(strArray[i].trim().length()>3){
            if(entries.size()!=0){
                IWiktionaryEntry Iwikiword=entries.get(0);
                List<IWikiString> words =Iwikiword.getGlosses();
                Iterator<IWikiString> wordItr = words.iterator();
                int k=0;
                System.out.println("Related Meanings of:"+strArray[i].trim().toUpperCase());
                System.out.println("Word List Size:"+words.size());
                System.out.println("Word List:"+words);
                System.out.println("Is List Empty:"+words.isEmpty());

                while(wordItr.hasNext()){
                    //System.out.println("["+k+"]"+":"+(IWikiString)wordItr.next());
                    System.out.println(k+":"+(IWikiString)wordItr.next());
                    k++;
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("*****No suitable meaning found for the word-"+strArray[i].trim().toUpperCase());
            }
          }
      }
```

This is what i see in console :
Related Meanings of:MEETING
Word List Size:1
Word List:[]
Is List Empty:false

### 0:

---

Related Meanings of:SCHEDULED
Word List Size:1
Word List:[]
Is List Empty:false
0:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have one element in your list, and that element's `toString()` method returns the empty `String`. This produces the output `[]` while returning `false` for `isEmpty()`:

```
List<String> output = Arrays.asList("");
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: e.g for word "BEEN" , output is following.
Word List Size:2
Word List:[, were]
Is List Empty:false
0:
1:were

So in this case what is the first element then?

Comment: That looks like a similar case. The first element is `""`, and the second is `were`.

Comment: Seems you are right.But i feel it a little strange that for "" it is still considerd an element while as it is just empty string